# Let $n=p^mr$ where $p$ is prime and $r\in\mathbb{Z_{>1}}$ such that $p\nmid r$. If $G$ is a simple group of order $n$ then $p^m\mid(r-1)!$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

**Question:** Let $n=p^mr$ where $p$ is prime and $r\in\mathbb{Z^{>1}}$ such that $p\nmid r$.  If $G$ is a simple group of order $n$ then $p^m\mid(r-1)!$.

**My Ideas:**  I feel like this should be a rather straightforward argument but I keep getting tripped up.  Since $G$ is simple, the only normal subgroups of $G$ are $\langle1\rangle$ and $G$. So, we have a homomorphism $\phi:G\rightarrow S_n$, where $n=1$ or $n=p^mr$. Since $G$ is simple, $\ker\phi=\langle1\rangle$.  If $n=1$, then we would violate the assumption that $r\in\mathbb{Z}_{>1}$.  .....and I am sort of stuck from here... maybe this isn't the best way to go about it?  Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. $G$ acts by left multiplication on the left cosets  of $P$ and since $G$ is simple the kernel of this action ($\cap_{g \in G}P^g=O_p(G)$) is trivial. Hence $G$ embeds in $S_r$, implying $p^mr$ divides $r!$ and you are done.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, if $p^mr \mid r!$, then $p^m \mid (r-1)!$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'll delete the comment.

Comment: @NickyHekster Looking back at this, how can we know that $n_p=r$?  I can see why $n_p\neq 1$, since $G$ is simple, but how do we know that it must be equal to $r$?

Comment: @User7328 $r=|G:P|$, so $r \neq n_p(G)$ in general. But as the answer of Qiaochu Yuan shows, you could start from $|G:N_G(P)|=n_p(G)$ and arrive at a shaper bound. In any case, $G$ acts by left (or right) multiplication on the left (or right) cosets of a subgroup $H$ and $G/core_G(H)$ embeds isomorphically in $S_{|G:H|}$. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You get a sharper bound by letting $G$ act on the conjugates of $P$ (the Sylow $p$-subgroups) instead of on the cosets; then there are $n_p = \frac{|G|}{|N_G(P)|} = \frac{r}{s}$ of these, where $s = \frac{|N_G(P)|}{|P|}$, and you get that $p^m r$ divides $n_p!$. If $r \not \equiv 1 \bmod p$ you're guaranteed that $n_p < r$ by the Sylow theorems so this bound will be strictly sharper in that case.

For example, if $|G| = 300$ and $p = 5$ then $r = 12$ and the given bound gives $25 \mid 11!$, which is true, but the sharper bound gives that $n_p = 6$ (it can't be equal to $1$ if $G$ is simple) so $25 \mid 5!$, which is a contradiction. So there's no simple group of order $300$.